# How to override the defined task order in a yocto recipe?

Tags: embedded-linux, yocto, bitbake

First some context with my problem:

I am trying to add some patches to modify some device trees from the source code used in linux-msm-4.4_git.bb recipe (which can be found in the [meta-qti-bsp](https://github.com/mcharleb/meta-qti-bsp) layer).

My linux-msm-4.4_git.bbappend looks like this:

```py
FILESEXTRAPATHS_append := "${THISDIR}/files:"

SRC_URI += " file://0001-patching-dts-stuff_1.patch"
SRC_URI += " file://0002-patching-dts-stuff_2.patch"
SRC_URI += " file://0003-patching-dts-stuff_3.patch"
SRC_URI += " file://0004-patching-dts-stuff_4.patch"
SRC_URI += " file://0005-patching-dts-stuff_5.patch"
SRC_URI += " file://0006-patching-dts-stuff_6.patch"
SRC_URI += " file://0007-patching-dts-stuff_7.patch"
SRC_URI += " file://0008-patching-dts-stuff_8.patch"
SRC_URI += " file://0009-patching-dts-stuff_9.patch"
```

But when I add my layer to the build/conf/bblayers.conf the recipe fails during the task **do_shared_workdir** because it doesn't find the **certs/signing_key.pem** file.

Trying to solve that error I found the following information:

meta-qti-bsp is slightly modified from the one that can be found in it's [repo](https://github.com/mcharleb/meta-qti-bsp) (I received the code in a zip file, so I don't know how many changes to externally maintained layers are made).

I followed all includes, inheritances and requires from the recipe in order to know what was happening:
[Here is an image of that.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6kPa3.jpg)

And I discovered that do_shared_workdir is overridden from kernel.bbclass.

When my layer **is not** included and I launch **bitbake linux-msm-4.4**, the execution order of the tasks is:

- fetch
- unpack
- prepare_recipe_sysroot
- unpack
- patch
- configure
- populate_lic
- compile
- shared_workdir
- kernel_link_images

When my layer is included **shared_workir** and **kernel_link_images** are always swapped in execution order.

So I tried if doing "**addtask shared_workdir after do_compile before kernel_link_images**" in my **.bbappend** overrides the "**addtask shared_workdir after do_compile before do_compile_kernelmodules**" from **kernel.bbclass**, to enforce the task order that doesn't end in error, which did not.

Modifying it in kernel.bbclass **did** solve the error, but I would rather not have to make changes in layers that are not maintained by me.

My main question:

- Is there a way to enforce the correct task order from my layer?

Another question which I would like to know the response in order to further understand the yocto framework:

If I created the layer using the command **bitbake-layers add-layer meta-mylayer**. I just added the same structure of recipes-*/*recipe-name*/*recipe*.bbappend that in the original layer, and this bbappend and it's files/*patches* are the only thing added by me. This patches and recipe do not define changes to task execution order.

- Why adding my layer causes the change of order in which this tasks are executed?

Comment: Did you look at [wiki](https://wiki.codeaurora.org/xwiki/bin/QLBEP/)? Maybe you should use google repo to get all meta-qti-bsp dependencies? (I'm not using this layer)

Comment: @Nayfe, I received the code in a zip. And when I launch "bitbake my-image" without my patches,  it runs successfully. So I suspect that the dependencies are present. Even though I have already solved it modifying the task order in the kernel.bbclass, I'm still interested in knowing a clean way to modify the task order in a bbappend file.